# How to write an array to a file without html

Tags: objective-c, arrays, text

The code I have right now looks like this:

```
NSString *path = @"/Users/student/Desktop/conf.txt"

NSArray *myArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"hello",@"world",@"etc",nil];

[myArray writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
```

When I look at the text file it writes it ends up looking like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN"     "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
    <string>hello</string>
     <string>world</string>
    <string>etc</string>
 </array>
 </plist>
```

I don't want to display it as an html, I just want a simple text document with the 3 lines saying, "hello world etc".

Does anybody know how I could fix this?

Thanks

Comment: It is not HTML, it is plist file format

Comment: Oh, I should have realized that. Any Idea of how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your array contains strings and you wat to write them to file one per line you can first create string with all your words and then write it to file:

```
NSString *outString = [myArray componentsJoinedByString:@"\n"];
NSError *error = nil;
[outString writeToFile: path atomically:YES encoding:encoding:NSUTF8Encoding error:&error];
```

But if you want to serialize your array for future use plist format may be more convenient

Comment: Thanks that worked great! But what do you mean by serialize? I'm still trying to pick up on all this stuff.

Comment: @Craig, I mean if later you want to read that array back and use again in application it will be more convenient to save and load it directly as array